# How to use a variable to embed a url link within a QLabel

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pyqt

Currently the code below works but i dont want the hyperlink to take me to google.com. I want it to take me to the link within the variable trailer.Could someone give me a suggestion.

```
trailers = page_soup.findAll("a",{"class":"slate_button prevent-ad-overlay video-modal"})[0]["href"]
imdbBase = "http://www.imdb.com"
trailer = imdbBase + trailers
urlLink=" <a href=\"http://www.google.com\"> <font face=Tw Cen MT Condensed size=2 color=black>Watch Trailer</font> </a>"
trailer_lbl = self.edit_trailer
self.edit_trailer.setText(urlLink)
self.edit_trailer.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```

Result from printing (trailers)

[image]

Comment: trailers returns a string. trailer is the concatenation of trailers and imdbBase

Comment: Thank you very much . I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Yeah it worked . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to concatenate a url you can use `format`:

```
trailers = "/video/imdb/vi38776120057?playlistId=tt0111161&ref=tt_ov_vi"
imdbBase = "http://www.imdb.com"

trailer = imdbBase + trailers
urlLink=" <a href=\"{url}\"> <font face=Tw Cen MT Condensed size=2 color=black>Watch Trailer</font> </a>".format(url=trailer)
trailer_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel()
trailer_lbl.setText(urlLink)
trailer_lbl.setOpenExternalLinks(True)
```